# which() removes all rows if returns integer(0)

Tags: r, rows

As in the title if I have a matrix `a` and I create `b` using a `which()` condition:

```
a <- data.frame(var1 = rep(1, 10),
            var2 = runif(10,1,2))

b <- a[-which(a$var1 == 2),]

> a
   var1     var2
1     1 1.758612
2     1 1.772328
3     1 1.224777
4     1 1.525981
5     1 1.300347
6     1 1.464542
7     1 1.060128
8     1 1.192889
9     1 1.923877
10    1 1.958677

> dim(b)
[1] 0 2
```

The `which(a$var1 == 2)` function returns `integer(0)` and removes all the rows of `a` . In an automated context, in which it is not possible to know a priori if a vale is not included (as the integer 2 in the example), how can I handle this issue?

Comment: What output are you looking for?

Comment: In the original context I remove everything is not `%in%` a vector, something like this: `a[-which(!a$var3 %in% c("a", "b")), ]` . So I want to remove everything IS NOT one of the two strings.

Comment: Skip the `which()`. `a[a$var1 != 2,]` or `a[!a$var1 %in% c(2, 3, 4),]`

Comment: @MartinMorgan that is by far the most logical answer. Perhaps you could post it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove indices using a vector which might be empty, you are safer to use `setdiff`:

```
b <- a[setdiff(seq_along(a$var1),which(a$var1 == 2)),]
b
   var1     var2
1     1 1.607701
2     1 1.898427
3     1 1.419441
4     1 1.685916
5     1 1.052964
6     1 1.924016
7     1 1.002527
8     1 1.873767
9     1 1.856852
10    1 1.092878
```

Comment: In the original context I remove everything is not `%in%` a vector, something like this: `a[-which(!a$var3 %in% c("a", "b")), ]` . So I want to remove everything IS NOT one of the two strings.

Comment: I'm getting a bit confused by the double negative. You want everything matching "a" or "b"?

Comment: Yes sir, I want to remove everything IS NOT "a" or "b".

Comment: The you can just use remove the minus sign and `which` in your expression and use the logical form of selection.

Answer (score 0):

The solution seems to avoid negating `which`, but you can negate the `%in%` :

```
set.seed(42)
a <- data.frame(var1 = 1:10,
        var2 = runif(10,1,2))

`%not_in%`<- Negate(`%in%`)
a[which(a$var1 %not_in% c(11,12)),]
#   var1     var2
#1     1 1.797066
#2     2 1.413511
#3     3 1.922845
#4     4 1.212539
#5     5 1.408266
#6     6 1.428282
#7     7 1.916336
#8     8 1.747179
#9     9 1.701980
#10   10 1.727161
```